# Defining a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to coding & I am taking ruby on rails online class. I have followed the lecture and documented everything but I am getting "NonMethod" error. Here what I have in my file

**Controller**

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search_term = 'jhu'
    @courses = Coursera.for(@search_term)
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
    class Coursera
    include HTTParty

    base_uri 'https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses'
    default_params fields: "smallIcon,shortDescription", q: "search"
    format :[enter image description here][1]json

    def self.for term
        get("", query: { query: term})["elements"]
    end
end
```

**Views**

```
<h1>Searching for - <%= @search_term %></h1>

<table border="1">
    <tr>

        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>

    </tr>
    <% @courses.each do |course| %>
        <tr class=<%= cycle('even', 'odd') %>>
            <td><%= image_tag(course["smallIcon"])%></td>
            <td><%= course["name"] %></td>
            <td><%= course["shortDescription"] %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
```

These are the messages I am getting

NoMethodError in Courses#index
Showing /Users/Dohe/my_app/app/views/courses/index.html.erb where line #11 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Can any help me with what I am doing wrong
Ruby 2.2.9 and Rails 4.2.3

Comment: Its just saying that the data you are trying to show by iterating is nil, so check if you have data for the search term and you should only be trying to iterate if there are data in the search results

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you can explain little bit, I would appreciate. As I said in my intro I am new to coding and my understanding my be little bit slow.

Answer (score 0):

As Subash stated in the comment, `@courses` is nil, which means that:

```
get("", query: { query: term})["elements"]
```

is returning `nil`. So, when you try `@courses.each`, you're getting the `NoMethod` error.

If you expect:

```
 get("", query: { query: term})["elements"]
```

not to be `nil`, then you'll have to debug that. You could show us your console logs and we might be able to help with that.

Also, to protect from the `NoMethod` error, you *could* do:

```
def self.for term
  get("", query: { query: term})["elements"] || []
end
```

This says, essentially, "return an empty array if `get("", query: { query: term})["elements"]` is `nil`". This will resolve your error, but could mask other problems you might be having. So, proceed with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Check what `@courses` contains in the controller, and change `<% end %>` to `<% end if @courses.present? %>` in your view, Its just making sure to only try to iterate through the `@courses` and populate it in the view if it actually contains any data, if it is `nil` then `nil` does not have a each method defined for it so you're getting the

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```